# texpad \input from non-root file

Tags: texpad

I am using texpad. I have a root file `main.tex` that has a command `\input{a}`. File `a.tex` itself has command `\input{b}`. But file b (that is, `b.tex`) does not show up in list of project files in the outline, and I am finding no way to open `b.tex` in the same project. (If I open `b.tex` separately, texpad thinks it is a new, separate project.) In outline, I can open root folder and see `b.tex` and select it. Can click on root folder word to get a add file to current project option. Clicking this does not succeed in adding `b.tex` to the project.